# Django - Filter on ManyToManyField

Tags: django, django-orm

I have two models:

```
class Student(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField()
    last_name = models.CharField()


class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    students = models.ManyToManyField(Student)
```

Some data (`first_name` and `last_name` concatenated):

```
Group #1 | Blak Coleman
Group #1 | Miguel Scott
Group #2 | Jordan Barnes
Group #2 | Jordan Gustman
Group #2 | Jekson Barnes
Group #3 | Jordan Smith
```

As you can see theres three students by name `Jordan`. So I need to return groups which in `students` queryset has only students by name `Jordan`.

I tried this:

```
groups = Group.objects.filter(students__first_name='Jordan')
```

But `group.first().students.all()` contains all the students not only Jordan. Expected result:

```
Group #2 | Jordan Barnes
Group #2 | Jordan Gustman
Group #3 | Jordan Smith
```

How could I do this?

Comment: What is meant by **But group.first().students.all() contains all the students not only Jordan**?

Comment: resultset name is `groups` - plural. `group.first().students.all()` - this code ignores your resultset. It refers `group` not `groups`. Show your full code related to the question.

Comment: Can you please answer my above comment?

Comment: @SunderamDubey, I posted the solution I found https://stackoverflow.com/a/74561823/9112151

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked:

```
from django.db.models import Prefetch

students = Student.objects.filter(first_name='Jordan')
prefetch = Prefetch('students', queryset=students)
groups = Group.objects.prefetch_related(prefetch)
groups = [group for group in groups if len(group.students.all())]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
groups = Group.objects.filter(students__first_name__in=['Jordan'])
```

Comment: Result is the same

Answer (score 0):

For all students you can write query like this...

```
groups = Group.objects.filter(students__id__in=[i.id for i in Students.objects.all()])
```